# Region Did Changed Accuracy

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have `MKMapView` and I need to do some action on `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)`. But this action is very hard to proceed every time when region changed, and I want to execute it only if region changed a lot. Example, from 1 city to another. Can you give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no built-in way to this with the mapview directly

---

1. have a member var called `_visitedRegionCenter : CLLocationCoordinate2D?`
2. when regionDidChangeAnimated compare the new `region.center` to the `_visitedRegionCenter` ... get the distance between the two coordinates using `CLLocation:: distanceFromLocation`
3. if the distance is bigger than e.g. 1000m do your thing, if it isn't, don't do it
4. IF distance was bigger than 1000, save the location of the new region. :: `region.center` and save it to `_visitedRegionCenter`

Comment: this way works, and I know about it, question is - if there any built in CLLocation / CLLocationManager functions or properties to track that?